# How to handle v-model in dynamic input fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a form where the user has the option to click an "Add" button and input content into new fields. I've currently dynamically generated the v-model for the fields, but I realized I need to register/return each of them in the setup function to use them.

How do I generate and register/return v-models for the different input fields if I don't know how many fields the user will decide to add?

```
<div
    v-for="(content, i) in contentFields"
    :key="i"
>
  <div>Content {{ i }}</div>
        <q-input
          :v-model="`contentName_` + i"
          outlined
          type="text"
          dense
        />
 </div></div>
```

Comment: If **content** is value for input ->`:v-model="contentFields[i]"

Comment: :v-model="`contentName_` + i" is returning string... Not an object / variable.

Comment: @digitalniweb don't I want it to be a string so that I can use that string in other parts of the code to refer to the entry the user made in the field? And if those fields are all different content, I thought I needed different v-model names.

Comment: @digitalniweb update: understand your comment. My way is wrong. How do I assign the correct v-model to an indeterminate number of input fields and then return/register those names so i can reference/use them in other areas in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at following snippet with simple dynamic v-models pls:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      contentFields: [{name: '', desc: ''}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addInput() {
      let newI = this.contentFields.length
      this.contentFields.push({name: '', desc: ''})
    },
    setD() {
      console.log(this.contentFields)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button @click="addInput">add</button>
  <div v-for="(content, i) in contentFields" :key="i">
    <div>Content {{ i }}</div>
      <input
        v-model="content.name"
        outlined
        type="text"
        dense
        @change="setD"
      />
      <input
        v-model="content.desc"
        outlined
        type="text"
        dense
        @change="setD"
      />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. (1) For "contentFields: [{0: ''}, {1: ''}]" in the data return, how would I add that for an unknown number of entries? What if one user adds one field but another user adds 10? (2) What would I do for the v-model if the v-for generated two content entries instead of just one?

Comment: Yes, it certainly does! But, but the code returns only two contentField entries under data, correct? "contentFields: [{0: ''}, {1: ''}]" -- Wouldn't that need to be increased if there were more than two entries?

Comment: Thanks again -- any suggestions on how to handle this with two input fields instead of just one? (e.g., if i had Content have an input field of a "name" and "description" each time ADD was clicked.

Comment: You are welcome, check now pls I updated answer :)